# Why the different Facebook App options - See image attached

Tags: facebook, facebook-oauth

I have 2 Facebook Apps setup: 1 returns email as the username and 1 doesn't.
I've checked the settings and the only thing different I can find is in this screenshot.

[image: The one of the right works, while the one on the left does not]

Does anyone know why I have a different view for each of these apps? The ovals-and-cube icon is not something I've added.

My only thought is that I've setup a different kind of app somehow, but I don't know which is which or whether I can change the one on the left to match the one on the right.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: One is an old one which as default uses an old version of the API. In the new version of the API you need to specify which fields you want. That works in the old API also

Comment: Thanks @WizKid, I'll check it out.

Comment: Any idea how to request the fields in asp.net??  I assume I have to do it in this line:
OpenAuth.AuthenticationClients.AddFacebook(appId: "<my app id>", appSecret: "<my app secret>",);